# Why is ParentComponent.childContextTypes and ChildComponent.contextTypes required?

Tags: reactjs

I am in the middle of learning React, and after reading about contexts, I keep wondering about this. Why is `ParentComponent.childContextTypes` and `ChildComponent.contextTypes` required for the child component to be able to receive contexts?

Answer (score 0):

Parent Component passes context to that subtree. So we will be mention which type of your context by using childContextTypes method.

Child Component receives context from their parent. In your app, there is a chance many parent component passes context as same names. So you define that type to identify these contexts.

In React JS Context API is one of the powerful API. So when you need this that time only use Context.